# IIS Does Session State persist across different applications (InProc)

Tags: asp.net, iis, session-variables, iis-8

I have to different ASP.NET applications (same version) running on the same IIS Server and I have Sessions running In Process. Will the session state/variables persist across the two applications? I found a similar post where someone asked the same question but they were managing sessions in SQL Server and someone pointed out explicitly that session state doesn't persist (out of the box) across two applications of Sessions were maintained using SQL Server. It made me wonder if the same applies by default for two applications where the sessions are maintained in process.

Answer (score -1):

No there is custom code needed.. best way that I found to do this.. is to have the referring page pass its session id and application name, then SQL stores the Session Data in a table using the [sessionid][appkey]... we use a reference table that I manually build to figure out the appkey for each new application... then I wrote a DLL that takes the string in and pulls the sessiondata from the DB and packs it in to the new pages current session.. Its a little tough to wrap you head around, but I can supply the DLL and how to use it if you want. Just PM me and ill get that DLL for you.